# my select and group statement find absolute max and minimum values

Tags: mysql

If I execeute select statement and group by say id, is it possible to return the resulting rows and also a a column maximum value for the whole result before it was grouped?

e,g

```
Select id, name year 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY id ASC

$rows = result;

$latest= absolute max value of year for all rows filtered?
```

or is the only way to do a groupwise maximum and get the absolute maximum from that?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use MySQL's `WITH ROLLUP` clause on your `GROUP BY`. It's fairly well documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html). *The benefit and/or drawback, is that the those "absolute" values are intermingled with normal results; so to get that final one, you have to get to the last result... at which point it would've been trivial to just keep track of largest and smallest values of the previous records.*